# Is there a way to stop an automated downloads organiser from relocating downloading files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, filesystems

I have written a short script to organise files in my downloads folder into specific subfolders. It unzips and then deletes archives, moves files out of subfolders and deletes them, and uses a dictionary to create and correctly fill the required subfolders.

All of this is working almost perfectly fine (unless a subfolder has the same name as a file), but I would like to autorun this script in the background.

However the issue I am facing is that when a file starts downloading, the script will immediately run and relocate the file, corrupting the download. Is there a way to ignore these files until complete? I'm using firefox, in case that's relevant.

Based on the other comment I've attempted this without result, but my function writing definitely needs work. Any tips on how I can achieve this?

```
def creation(check):
        x = os.stat(check)
        return (time.time() - x.st_mtime)

    # Directory Path
    PATH = Path("/Users/jobe/Downloads")

    for filename in PATH.iterdir():

        path_to_file = filename.absolute()

        if creation(path_to_file) > 3600:
            if path_to_file.is_file():
                destination = PATH / get_dir(filename)

            if not destination.exists():
                destination.mkdir()

            move(str(path_to_file), str(destination))
```

Comment: You could put something together using Firefox's WebExtensions API, which could then communicate with your Python script, but that requires JavaScript.

Comment: I'm super new to coding, can barely get my head around python, let alone JavaScript. But thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy option that is fairly fool proof as to what browser you're using would be to check the age of the file like this

```py
import os 
import time 
x=os.stat('file_name')
Result=(time.time()-x.st_mtime)
```

and then say if that time is less than 1 hour old, don't sort it. The fringe case would be files that take longer than that set time to download.

Comment: So i would just use an 'if' checking the file age before it runs through the current sorting loops? This definitely seems like it would work. Thank you

Comment: @Jobe-T Correct, I think it will return the file age in seconds so you would do something like if file_age < 3600 don't sort.

Comment: I've edited based on your suggestion but I think I've got the function wrong. I edited in the newly implemented code if you have any tips on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Jobe-T looking at that it looks like you have a formatting issue, could you correct it?